# Setting _fields_ dynamically in ctypes.Structure

Tags: python, ctypes

Reading the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html), I see that you can use ctypes.Structure as follows :-

```
>>> class Int(Structure):
...     _fields_ = [("first_16", c_int, 16),
...                 ("second_16", c_int, 16)]
...
>>> print Int
```

Would it be possible for me to create such a class by using a list that I decide upon dynamically? For eg, something along the lines of :-

```
def int_factory(fields):
    int_class = get_int_class(fields) # This returns a class object with _fields_ set to fields
    return int_class

def user(values=[1,2]):
    int_class = int_factory(int_fields)
    i = int_class(values[0], values[1])
```

Would it be possible to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example below:

- *int_factory* generates the *Int* class
- *user* returns an *Int* instance with *first_16* set to ***1***, and *second_16* set to ***2***

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys


def int_factory(fields):
    return type("Int", (cts.Structure,), {"_fields_": fields})


def user(values=[1, 2]):
    int_fields = (("first_16", cts.c_int, 16), ("second_16", cts.c_int, 16))  # This is just an example to illustrate your class definition. int_fields can be generated dynamically.
    int_class = int_factory(int_fields)
    int_obj = int_class(*values)
    return int_obj


def print_int_obj_data(int_obj):
    print("Type: {:}\n_fields_: {:}".format(int_obj.__class__.__name__, int_obj._fields_))
    for field in int_obj._fields_:
        print("    {:}: {:}".format(field[0], getattr(int_obj, field[0])))


def main(*argv):
    int0 = user()
    print_int_obj_data(int0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                    64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q030799760]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_02.07.18_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 2.7.18 (v2.7.18:8d21aa21f2, Apr 20 2020, 13:25:05) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Type: Int
> _fields_: (('first_16', <class 'ctypes.c_long'>, 16), ('second_16', <class 'ctypes.c_long'>, 16))
>     first_16: 1
>     second_16: 2
>
> Done.
> ```

Might also check [[SO]: Dynamically defining/updating ctypes structure in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57438020/4788546).

Comment: In Python 3 if you use a `class` statement instead of calling `type`, the compiler defines the class  `__qualname__` attribute, such as `int_factory.<locals>.Int`. If you don't need a custom class name, you may as well use a `class` statement. Otherwise you could mimic this using `{'_fields_': fields, '__qualname__': '%s.<locals>.%s' % (sys._getframe().f_code.co_name, class_name)}`.