# Dynamically defining/updating ctypes structure in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, python-2.x

I have created subtructure and structure in ctypes as below where I am defining a array of substructure inside structure with some predefined size. (As per requirement `SIZE` may be set to `0` initially and can varies based on user input).

```py
from ctypes import *

class MySubStructure(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("sub_field1", c_uint32),
        ("sub_field2", c_uint32)
    ]


class MyStructure(Structure):
    SIZE = 2
    _fields_ = [
        ("field1", c_uint32),
        ("field2", c_uint32),
        ("sub_structure_field", ARRAY(SubStructure, SIZE)),
    ]
```

My goal is to modify this substructure based on user input.

For achieving the same I have tried below options but had no success:

1. Defining a `__init__` method and updating `_fields_` while initializing the instance
2. Updating `_fields_` after initializing instance

For both of those options I tried to appending `sub_structure_field`, updating only size value by accessing through index.

Finally I just want a workaround so that I can use array of structure inside another structure either initializing at runtime or modifying at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioning [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

The array size must be known at the moment *_fields_* is defined. 
You could have a factory function which defines the class and returns it.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys


class SubStructure(cts.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ("sub_field1", cts.c_uint32),
        ("sub_field2", cts.c_uint32),
    )


def structure_factory(size):
    class DynamicStructure(cts.Structure):
        _fields_ = (
            ("field1", cts.c_uint32),
            ("field2", cts.c_uint32),
            ("sub_structure_field", SubStructure * size),  # Equivalent to: cts.ARRAY(SubStructure, size)
        )

    return DynamicStructure


def main(*argv):
    Struct2 = structure_factory(2)  # DynamicStructure type NOT instance
    Struct5 = structure_factory(5)  # -- // --
    print(Struct2.sub_structure_field)
    print(Struct5.sub_structure_field)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057417435]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> <Field type=SubStructure_Array_2, ofs=8, size=16>
> <Field type=SubStructure_Array_5, ofs=8, size=40>
>
> Done.
> ```

You could also take a look at [[SO]: Setting _fields_ dynamically in ctypes.Structure (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30801487/4788546).