# Create ctypes structure instance ignoring buffer size

Tags: python, python-3.6, ctypes

I have a ctypes structure but some elements will vary in size depending on the contents which I receive at runtime.  The length of the field is defined in the structure prior to the actual field.  Therefore, I create an instance given an initial structure, read the length, then resize the structure with the correct field length and repeat this until I've resize all the variable length fields.

```
structI=structP.from_buffer_copy(buf)
structP=rebuildStructFcn(structP,'element1',structI.element1.fieldsize)
structI=structP.from_buffer_copy(buf)
structP=rebuildStructFcn(structP,'element2',structI.element2.fieldsize)
structI=structP.from_buffer_copy(buf)
structP=rebuildStructFcn(structP,'element3',structI.element3.fieldsize)
structFinalInstance=structP.from_buffer_copy(buf)
```

Example, buf is a bytearray buffer of data I receive.  structP is a ctypes.Structure I've setup. rebuildStructFcn will modify structP resizing a field.  I do this in order ofcourse.  This code works except as I resize the structure, I can run into a situation where the structure is too large for the buffer.  Then I will get:

```
ValueError: Buffer size too small (7108 instead of at least 7252 bytes)
```

Is there a way to force it?  I don't care if the buffer is too small because I am reading in order and not jumping to the end.

Comment: There are some statements in your question that don't seem right. Please post your code ([\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). In the mean time, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799760/setting-fields-dynamically-in-ctypes-structure/30801487#30801487.

Comment: I second that  - viewing the struct-factory on Python side, and the original C struct itself would make it easier to answer this. The nature of the error suggests something extra being computed on the Python side of the struct.